# Android Studio Error while compiling an apk

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I want to create my apk file for my project, but I get the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>    com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zznf;

This is my Build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.wp.fyriaxis"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 5
    versionName "1.3"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"


}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hint is that `Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms`

Meaning some of Google packages are conflicting.

The Firebase and Google play services versions must match